# Fill object data from several tables using hibernate mapping

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I'd like to know if it is possible to fill up a class data from database using the hibernate hbm (mapping).

For instance:

```
public class someClass {  
    List<OtherClass> otherClasses;  
    List<YetAnotherClass> yetAnotherClasses;  
    //Constructors ?  

    class OtherClass {  
        String name;  
        //setters, getters  
    }  

    class YetAnotherClass {  
        String name;  
        //setters, getters  
    }
    //setters, getters  
}
```

Using an hbm can I fill in the data from tables OTHER_CLASS_TABLE and YET_ANOTHER_CLASS_TABLE?

I have no such SOME_CLASS_TABLE since this info is for viewing only.

I've been playing with the `<join table=""><subselect>` and different   constructors...  But it is not working

Thanks!

Sorry for my english!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a class which seems not to be a real entity, since it does not have identity to start with, right? Then I woulf guess you can't map it directly.

Depending on how do you actually use `someClass`, I can think of the following workarounds:

- if it is part of an entity, you could try mapping it as `component` - but then again, you could simply map the contained lists directly in this case
- if it is simply used to store query results, you could put together a scalar query to return the contents of the two lists, then assemble your objects from the results

Comment: éter: actually it is a result of a complicated SQL query. I wonder if I could map it in hibernate and then retrieveit as an instance.

Comment: @Udo, there _might_ be a way to map it but I am not aware of it (then again, I am not a Hibernate guru). But assembling the object from a scalar query result should work, even if it may not be an elegant solution.